# finding the max and min in a tree without using flatten

Tags: clojure, tree, max, min

I need to Develop a function called bounds which takes a nested list of numbers as its only argument (ie: a tree). Bounds should return the largest &smallest value in the tree. Eg:

```
(bounds '(1 (-2 17 (4) -8 (-6 13) (-8 17))))
```

Using clojure and not using the flatten function but using recursion to visit each node

(defn maxv [tree]
  (cond
    (number? tree) tree

```
(tree? tree)
(let [newmax (maxv (first tree)) ]
```

;;let newmax be the first in the tree
      (if (< newmax (maxv (first (rest tree))))
;; if the next in the tree is smaller
            (= (newmax (maxv (first (rest tree)))))
;;change newmax to this
              (recur (maxv (rest tree)))))
;; recur through the rest

this is what i have i think i am being too java ish

Comment: and what have you tried so far?  please include your code so others can build on it.

Comment: @Mark This is clearly not the way to write code. I've noticed that you've already asked a similar questions and you were given the insight that 'flatten' does the recursion for you. Also, you aren't showing any code of what you tried so that we can provide you with guidance. You should also state why 'flatten' doesn't work for you.

Comment: (defn sum-tree [tree]
  (cond
    (number? tree) tree

    (tree? tree)
    (+ (sum-tree (first tree))
       (sum-tree (rest tree)))

    :else 0
    ))

(def nums1 '(1 ((2) 3) (4 (5 (6 7) 8) 9)))

user=> (sum-tree nums1)
45

Comment: (defn maxv [tree]
  (cond
    (number? tree) tree

    (tree? tree)
    (let [newmax (maxv (first tree)) ]
      (if (< newmax (maxv (first (rest tree))))
            (= (newmax (maxv (first (rest tree)))))
              (recur (maxv (rest tree)))))

    :else 0
    ))

Answer (score 1):

`flatten` is *very efficient*, so there is **no benefit** in implementing it yourself.

If your nested list is not too big, you could `apply` `(juxt min max)` directly to the flattened list:

```
(defn bounds [coll]
  (apply (juxt min max) (flatten coll)))
```

For large input collections I would recommend using `reduce` instead of `apply`:

```
(defn bounds [coll]
  (reduce (fn [[minv maxv :as res] v]
            (if res [(min minv v) (max maxv v)] [v v]))
          nil
          (flatten coll)))
```

If you really need pure recursive implementation, here is an example for you:

```
(defn bounds [coll]
  (loop [coll coll [minv maxv :as res] nil]
    (if-let [[h & ts] (seq coll)]
      (if (sequential? h)
          (recur (concat h ts) res)
          (recur ts (if res [(min minv h) (max maxv h)] [h h])))
      res)))
```

All three implementation will yield you a tuple containing min and max values:

```
(bounds '(1 (-2 17 (4) -8 (-6 13) (-8 17)))) ; => [-8 17]
```

## Update: note on `sum-tree` implementation from comments

It's a very bad idea to use [multiple recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Single_recursion_and_multiple_recursion) in your code, because it'll blow your stack very quickly:

```
(sum-tree (range 7000)) ; => java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Try using [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) with [recur](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur), or [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) instead:

```
(defn sum-tree [tree]
  (if (number? tree)
      tree
      (reduce + (map sum-tree tree))))
```

Comment: What's about my recursive implementation then? Is it what you need?

Comment: @MarkWilson you shouldn't use [multiple recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Single_recursion_and_multiple_recursion) in your code, because it'll blow your stack very quickly.

Comment: @MarkWilson added brief explanation what's wrong with your `sum-tree` and how you could fix it.